# Zoom in Bar Chart

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to implement zoom in Bar Chart but unfortunatly unsuccessful. Can you help me to fix this code?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.scene.transform.Transform;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;

public class FreehandResize extends Application {

 private CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
 private NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0.53000, 0.53910, 0.0001);
 private LineChart<String, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<String, Number>       (xAxis, yAxis);
 private Path path;
 private double initialWidth;
 private double initialheight;
 private Translate translate = new Translate(0, 0);
 private Scale scale = new Scale(1, 1);
 private ChangeListener<Number> changeListener = new ChangeListener<Number>() {

    @Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
  Bounds y_axisBounds = yAxis.getBoundsInLocal();
  double xOffset = y_axisBounds.getMaxX();

  translate.setX(xOffset);

  Bounds chartBounds = lineChart.getBoundsInLocal();
  scale.setX((chartBounds.getWidth() - xOffset) / initialWidth);
  scale.setY((chartBounds.getHeight() - xAxis.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()) / initialheight);
    }
  };
private EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

  double targetX = (mouseEvent.getX() - translate.getX()) / scale.getX();
  double targetY = mouseEvent.getY() / scale.getY();

  if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(targetX, targetY));
  } else if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(targetX, targetY));
  }
}

 };

   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) {
   stage.setTitle("Resize line plot");

   yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis) {

  @Override
  public String toString(Number object) {
    return String.format("%6.4f", object);
  }
});

lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
lineChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);

XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 0.53185));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 0.532235));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 0.53234));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 0.538765));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 0.53442));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 0.534658));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 0.53023));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 0.53001));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 0.53589));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 0.53476));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 0.530123));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 0.53035));
lineChart.getData().addAll(series1);

BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
pane.setCenter(lineChart);

Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
stage.setScene(scene);

path = new Path();
path.setStrokeWidth(2);
path.setStroke(Color.CHOCOLATE);

ObservableList<Transform> transforms = path.getTransforms();
transforms.add(0, translate);
transforms.add(1, scale);

scene.setOnMouseClicked(mouseHandler);
scene.setOnMouseDragged(mouseHandler);
scene.setOnMouseEntered(mouseHandler);
scene.setOnMouseExited(mouseHandler);
scene.setOnMouseMoved(mouseHandler);
scene.setOnMousePressed(mouseHandler);
scene.setOnMouseReleased(mouseHandler);

pane.getChildren().add(path);

scene.widthProperty().addListener(changeListener);
scene.heightProperty().addListener(changeListener);

stage.show();
Bounds axisBounds = yAxis.getBoundsInLocal();
double xOffset = axisBounds.getMaxX();
translate.setX(xOffset);

Bounds chartBounds = lineChart.getBoundsInLocal();
initialWidth = chartBounds.getWidth() - xOffset;
initialheight = chartBounds.getHeight() - xAxis.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
 }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Zoom and Pan is implemented in this open source lib: https://github.com/gillius/jfxutils

You could use it or learn from its source.